# Locale errors when installing packages

Tags: locale

I'm trying to install some packages like Zeroconf and TightVNC.
Install seems to go fine but each time I get a notice like this in Terminal:

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
```

Is this something I need to worry about or can easily fix?

Comment: I am assuming that you recently changed the locale for your Pi, if so this is not an issue, and will likely disappear after a reboot.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Locale-Categories.html

Comment: @SteveRobillard I rebooted but still got the errors when installing apache

Comment: Did you set a default locale? Here are a few other links with solutions http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=50&t=11870 http://hexample.com/2012/02/05/fixing-locale-problem-debian/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Commenting out `SendEnv LANG LC_*` in my mac's /etc/ssh_config fixed it!

Answer (score 4):

With latest Raspbian release `Jessie`, you can set the `LC_ALL` to value `C` in `~/.bashrc` file and everything else would set to what you choose and you wouldn't get any warning or error messages. Here's how -

Open your `.bashrc` file with `nano` editor -

```
sudo nano ~/.bashrc
```

Now add below line to the end of the file -

```
export LC_ALL=C
```

Save the file, reboot your Pi and everything should be fixed. Hope it helps.

Comment: was already fixed, but thanks for the tip anyway, could prove useful in the future. Out of curiosity: why do you wrap backticks around ~/.bashrc? It works fine without them.

Comment: Oops..! It was a typo mistake, i wanted to highlight it as a code block. Removed it. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: Why the `sudo`?

Comment: Just a precaution if you dont have admin access to the file.