# locale settings Issues

Tags: raspbian, database, locale

I'm trying to connect to psql using the below command but receiving message about unset local setting how could one solve it.

```
 pi@raspberrypi ~/develop/radar $ psql -U postgres
    perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
    perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
            LANGUAGE = (unset),
            LC_ALL = (unset),
            LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
            LANG = "en_GB.UTF-8"
        are supported and installed on your system.
    perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
    psql: FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Comment: /etc/bash.bashrc:export LC_ALL='en_GB.utf8' Remove or edit this line.

Answer (score 8):

- Run `raspi-config`.
- Select `4 Internationalisation Options`.
- Within that submenu, complete:

  - `I1 Change Locale`
  - `I2 Change Timezone`

However, the warning from perl about locale is not necessarily the reason you are failing authentication.

Comment: keep receiving errors such as: /usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/usr/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory

Comment: Yeah, I've seen this one [repeatedly over at U&L](http://unix.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bdebian%5D+locale+is%3Aquestion), but for some people nothing seems to work.  I'm sure I've solved it [this way](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169138/25985) before (the manual way, starting by editing `locale.gen`), but I don't think Raspbian should suffer that problem that way in the first place, particularly if you've run `raspi-config`.  Really it shouldn't blow up like this anywhere though, so worth a check.

Comment: So the standard Debian method `dpkg-reconfigure locales` and `dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` aren't supported on Raspbian or what?

Answer (score 8):

I was having a very similar issue. Here's how I fixed it:

Run `sudo nano /etc/default/locale`

Change it to include these three lines:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then reboot the system and it should be updated.

Answer (score 3):

With the new raspbian release `Jessie`, this can be done easily by just setting the `LC_ALL` value to `C`. Here's a [link of that solution](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/40146/33887) that i updated on another question. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

Scriptable solution:

```
sudo -i

echo "en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8" > /etc/locale.gen
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8

echo "LANG=en_US.UTF-8" > /etc/default/locale
update-locale en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score 2):

I met the same problem when using SSH to connect my PI.
I noticed that configuration in PI is different from locale settings in my computer.

I change the /etc/default/locale in BOTH pi and computer to the same, and solved.

Hope it helps to others.