# Dropbox page display issue

Tags: web-browsers

I'm very new to raspberry pi and stuck on a day I've started.
Problem I struggle is related to font.
I'll upload a picture to illustate issue rather than words[image]

It should be some language setting I should've make mistake.
May I ask you for help?

Comment: Welcome! Picture makes sense, but an additional textual description makes it easier for others (i.e. search engines) to find this in future. Anyway: I would check the language settings of Rasbian ( https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/38020/78211 ) and Firefox.

Comment: on the command line, type `sudo raspi-config`, then change the `localisation options`